Disable Firefox feature to choose its own DNS
Let's say I have set up a PC Windows to use 1.1.1.3 Cloudflare "Family" DNS (no "adult" websites) as computer DNS (in the connection/network adapter settings).
Then navigating on these websites is disabled (ok it's only at DNS level, and not a total protection of course, but it's better than nothing).
But Firefox has a feature to choose its own DNS, so it's very easy for a user to choose 1.1.1.1 again which won't block anything, and have access to full internet.

Is there a Windows "group policy" or similar hidden feature in Firefox to disable Firefox users to choose their own DNS?
(I use a policies.json file, but I don't find the specific setting to remove the ability to change DNS settings: https://mozilla.github.io/policy-templates)
This is a common problem for sys admin of school computers.
How do they prevent Firefox users to choose their own DNS?

Firefox supports enterprise policy. Surely there’s a switch available for that.

@DanielB Yes I use a policies.json, but I don't find the specific setting to remove the ability to change DNS settings: https://mozilla.github.io/policy-templates/

Out of curiosity: did you also disable the user's ability to install other browsers? Or to use a VPN or a proxy? Or to use their mobile device's mobile data plan? Or to use Microsoft Bing Video to watch adult content? Or to visit NSFW subreddits? Or to use Twitter? Or to join NSFW Discord servers? Or any of the myriad other ways to circumvent an adult filter?

@Nzall, I also did prevent some of the other things you mentioned, yes. But not all of course. We probalby agree that education about the use of internet is the key, and "blocking only" is of course not the solution, and can easily be defeated, yes. I agree with all of that. Nevertheless, it's not totally useless either to take a few steps to activate parental controls...

Looks like there is an option for configuring DNSOverHTTPS (DoH):
https://mozilla.github.io/policy-templates/#dnsoverhttps
policies.json:
{
  "policies": {
    "DNSOverHTTPS": {
      "Enabled":  true | false,
      "ProviderURL": "URL_TO_ALTERNATE_PROVIDER",
      "Locked": true | false,
      "ExcludedDomains": ["example.com"],
      "Fallback": true | false,
    }
  }
}


Enabled determines whether DNS over HTTPS is enabled
ProviderURL is a URL to another provider.
Locked prevents the user from changing DNS over HTTPS preferences.
ExcludedDomains excludes domains from DNS over HTTPS.
Fallback determines whether or not Firefox will use your default DNS resolver if there is a problem with the secure DNS provider.

Setting Enabled to false and setting Locked to true will disable the feature and prevent changing the setting (confirmed working):
{
  "policies": {
    "DNSOverHTTPS": {
      "Enabled": false,
      "Locked": true
    }
  }
}

